# Lower bound for a conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

How can we show this must hold knowing that x is an exponential distribution with mean = 4? (Last time I forgot to include what x was!)

$$E\left( \Bigl(\frac{2}{3} \Bigr)^x \ \middle| \ x \ge 6 \right) \ge \Bigl(\frac{2}{3} \Bigr)^{10}$$

I have no idea how to start this question. Any hint what this question is about? any specific type of inequality? lower bound of a conditional distribution?

Thanks.

Comment: The memorylessness property of the exponential distribution implies that conditioned on $X \ge 6$, the random variable $X-6$ also follows an exponential distribution with the same mean. So ultimately the conditional expectation is the same as $E[(2/3)^{X+6}]$.

Comment: Thanks @angryavian for your response. Yeah, I know that property of exponential distributions, but what I'm stuck at is that (2/3)^10. Why does the left part have to be greater than or equal to (2/3)^10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memorylessness of the exponential distribution the left-hand side is equal to $E[(2/3)^{X+6}]$ so it remains to show $$E[(2/3)^X] \ge (2/3)^4.$$

---

**Direct approach.**
With $\lambda=1/4$,
$$E[(2/3)^X]
= \int_0^\infty (2/3)^x \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx
= \lambda \int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda + \log(3/2))x} \, dx
= \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \log (3/2)}
= \frac{1}{1+4\log(3/2)}$$
and you can check numerically that this is larger than $(2/3)^4$.

I may be overlooking a simpler approach for proving the inequality though.

Comment: Thanks @angryvian. I think we can use the Jensen's inequality for the whole thing. Right? Which will be $E(f(x)) \ge f(E(x))$ where $f(x) = (\frac{2}{3})^{x+6}$. So, $E(f(x)) \ge f(4) = (\frac{2}{3})^{6+4}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @RamZi Ah yes that is probably the intended approach. nice job!